# Using custom domains with Firebase Dynamic Links

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-dynamic-links

I've written a Google Apps Script function that shortens the URL using Firebase's Dynamic Links -

```js
function fbURLShort() {
  var data = {
    "dynamicLinkInfo": {
      "domainUriPrefix": "https://example.page.link",
      "link": "https://example.com/lenghtlyURL?with=hooks&more=additions"
    },
    "suffix": {
      "option": "SHORT"
    }
  };
  var url = "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=myAPIkey"
  var options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    "contentType": "application/json",
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    "muteHttpExceptions":true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(response)
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var obj = data["shortLink"];
  Logger.log(obj)
}
```

This works perfectly well when using the **example.page.link** domainUriPrefix; however, there is also a way to [Connect a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain?authuser=0) and I've been able to successfully do that too (this domain would show up under Firebase's Hosting section).

However, when I replace *example.page.link* with **customdomain.com**, it throws the following error -

```html
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Your project does not own Dynamic Links domain: https://customdomain.com [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_parameters]",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
```

Now, what I want to do is use *said* custom domain as a base link to shorten URLs instead of .page.link (via Dynamic Links).
How do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to use a full custom domain for Firebase Dynamic Links. Custom subdomains under `page.link` are all that is available.

That said, we've heard this request before. So if you're really interested in it, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Answer (score 0):

as of November 2019 it is possible to do this, with up to 10 domains, custom or *.page.link domains.... as long as they all share the same suffix :(